# Behaviour of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}\left(\sqrt{n^2+n} - \sqrt{n^2+1}\right)^n x^n$ for $|x|=2$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I want to determine the radius of convergence for the power series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(\sqrt{n^2+n} - \sqrt{n^2+1})^n}{n^2} x^n$$

and determine what happens at the boundaries. I determined the ratio of convergence $R$ to be $2$, but I struggle to show that it converges on $x = \pm 2$. Can you give me a hint?

---

What I have so far: $R = \frac{1}{\limsup_{n \to \infty} (x_n)} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{1+1}} = \frac{2}{1} = 2$, where

$$\begin{align} x_n := \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} &= \sqrt[n]{| \frac{(\sqrt{n^2+n} - \sqrt{n^2+1})^n}{n^2}|} = \frac{\sqrt{n^2+n} - \sqrt{n^2+1}}{1} \\ &= \frac{(n^2+n) - (n^2+1)}{\sqrt{n^2+n} + \sqrt{n^2+1}} = \frac{(n^2+n) - (n^2+1)}{\sqrt{n^2+n} + \sqrt{n^2+1}} \\ &= \frac{n - 1}{\sqrt{n^2+n} + \sqrt{n^2+1}} = \frac{1 - \frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} + \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}} \end{align}$$

How do I determine if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(\sqrt{n^2+n} - \sqrt{n^2+1})^n}{n^2} (\pm 2)^n$ converges? The root test doesn't work and the ratio test doesn't seem to be a smart move. What can I do?

Comment: For $x=-2$ it's obvious converges.

Comment: Where is the problem? By your own conputations, the $n$th term is equivalent (in the mathematical, precise, meaning of the term) to $$\frac{(n-1)^n}{2^nn^n\cdot n^2}x^n\sim\frac{x^n}{e\cdot2^n\cdot n^2}$$ hence, if $x=\pm2$, then...

Comment: @Did I don't really see, where the $2^n n^n$ in the denominator come from? Which approximations did you use?

Comment: None. Only the computations about $x_n$ in your own post.

Comment: @Did Sorry, but I don't see them. Otherwise I also wouldn't have asked the question. Maybe you can share a bit more detail? Why not write an answer that I can accept then?

Comment: Didn't you show that $$a_n=\frac1{n^2}\left(\sqrt{n^2+n} - \sqrt{n^2+1}\right)^n$$ is also $$a_n=\frac1{n^2}\frac{(1-1/n)^n}{(\sqrt{1+1/n} + \sqrt{1+1/n^2})^n}\ ?$$ Then, $$(\sqrt{1+1/n} + \sqrt{1+1/n^2})^n=(2+1/2n+o(1/n))^n=2^n(1+1/4n+o(1/n))^n\sim2^ne^{1/4}$$ hence $$a_n\sim\frac1{n^2\cdot e\cdot2^n\cdot e^{1/4}}$$ In particular, if $|x|=2$ then $$|a_nx^n|\sim\frac{c}{n^2}$$ with $c\ne0$, which should be enough to conclude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to bound the sequence here after we call it $a_n$. Note that the following inequalities hold:

$$a_n={{(\sqrt{n^2+n}-\sqrt{n^2+1})^n}\over{n^2}}x^n$$$$={{(n-1)^n}\over{n^2}(\sqrt{n^2+n}+\sqrt{n^2+1})^n}x^n$$$$\le {{(n-1)^n}\over{n^2}(2n)^n}x^n$$$$\le{{n^n}\over{n^2}(2n)^n}={{({x\over 2})^n}\over{n^2}}=b_n$$

where $b_n$ obviously converges when $|{x\over 2}|\le 1$ or $|x|\le 2$.

Now we try to bound $a_n$ from bottom. We have :

$$a_n\ge {{(n-1)^n}\over{n^2}(\sqrt{n^2+n+{1\over 4}}+\sqrt{n^2+n+{1\over 4}})^n}x^n={{(n-1)^n}\over{n^2}(2n+1)^n}x^n={1\over {n^2}}({{n-1}\over{2n+1}})^nx^n={1\over {n^22^n}}(1-{3\over{2n+1}})^{{{2n}\over 3}{3\over 2}}x^n$$

Now note that the term $(1-{3\over{2n+1}})^{{{2n}\over 3}{3\over 2}}$ tends to $e^{3\over2}$ which is a constant so

$$a_n=\Theta({1\over {n^2}}({x\over 2})^n)$$
 which diverges when $|x|>2$ so is $a_n$. Therefore we finally deduce that the radius of convergence is $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$\sqrt{n^2+n}=n\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{\frac12}\sim n+\frac12 \quad \sqrt{n^2+1}=n\left(1+\frac1{n^2}\right)^{\frac12}\sim n$$

$$\left(\sqrt{n^2+n} - \sqrt{n^2+1}\right)^n\sim\frac{1}{2^n}$$

thus

$$\frac1{n^2}\left(\sqrt{n^2+n} - \sqrt{n^2+1}\right)^n x^n \sim \frac{x^n}{2^nn^2}$$

which diverges when $|x|>2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(\sqrt{n^2+n} - \sqrt{n^2+1}\right)^n}{n^2}x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^n\left(\sqrt{1+\frac1n} - \sqrt{1+\frac1{n^2}}\right)^n}{n^2}x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^n\left(\left(1+\frac1{2n}-\frac1{8n^2}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\right) - \left(1+\frac1{2n^2}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)\right)\right)^n}{n^2}x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(\frac12-\frac5{8n}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)^n}{n^2}x^n\\[3pt]
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-5/4}+O\!\left(\frac1n\right)}{2^nn^2}x^n
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the radius of convergence is $2$, and the series converges absolutely at the boundaries